# how to remove unwanted space after newline when using cat in r

Tags: r, cat

```r
> cat(c("A\n", "B"))
A
 B
```

I don't know why this is. How can this be fixed?

Comment: use `cat(c("A\n", "B"), sep='')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
cat(c("A\n", "B"), sep='')
```

Or also:

```
cat(c('A', 'B'), sep='\n')
```